# zsh - read user input with default value - empty input not empty?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, zsh, ksh

I wrote a function that asks for user input like this:

```
function is_confirmed {

    read -rs -k 1 ans

    if [[ "${ans}" == "n" || "${ans}" == "N" ]]; then
        printf "No\n"
        return 1
    fi

    if [[ "${ans}" == "y" || "${ans}" == "Y" ]]; then
        printf "Yes\n"
        return 0
    fi

    # here is my actual problem!!! this doesnt work when user input is blank!
    if [[ "${ans}" == "" ]]; then
        printf "Yes!\n"
        return 1
    fi

    # Output is Damn!
    printf "Damn"
    return 1
}
```

works great so far, however, I want to set "yes" as the default answear, so when the user inputs nothing and just presses enter, it should fall back to "yes", so I tried it with `|| "$ans" == ""` but that still falls back to "Damn"

how come? When I `echo $ans` at the end of the function it is empty...

EDIT 1:

This is what happens:

```
e_ask "Are you sure you want to install?\nWarning: This may override some files in your home directory."

if is_confirmed; then
    echo "Great!"
else
    e_error "Aborting..."
fi
```

here are the functions:

```
function e_ask {
    printf "\n$1\n"
    printf "(Y/n): "
}

function e_warn {
    printf "Warning: $1\n"
}

function e_error {
    printf "Error: $1\n"
    exit 1
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`case`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#index-case) is better when you want to consider many different values and a default one

```
function is_confirmed {

    read -rs -k 1 ans

    case "${ans}" in
    y|Y|$'\n')
        printf "Yes\n"
            return 0
        ;;

    *)  # This is the default
        printf "No\n"
            return 1

    esac

}
```

Comment: that doesn't answear my question. when I type nothing into the shell and just press enter, so that the $ans should be an empty string, `$ans == ""` still falls back to "Damn".

Comment: @MartinBroder Sorry, I misunderstood.  Do you want to print "No" if you enter `N` or `n`, and "Yes" if you enter `y`, `Y` or nothing? In this case you only need to change the default case or replace `y|Y` with `y|Y|""`.

Comment: No problem,
Well yes I want to print "Yes" when the input is `Y`,`y`," " and "No" when it is `N`,`n` OR whatever else ( `a`,`b`,`c` ... )

Comment: thanks alot, I updated my question, this is exactly my problem. `""` doesnt work. :/

Comment: @MartinBroder it isn't actually an empty string but a newline character, I've updated the answer, now should work.

Comment: It does! Phew. Thanks alot! How did you find out?

Comment: Using a simple debug: print the actual value of `ans`: `echo "\"$ans\""`.  `;-)`

Answer (score 3):

Just add default variable in the beginning of function:

```
function is_confirmed {

    ans="y"

    echo "Put your choice:"
    read $ans


}
```

If nothing is typed in, default value will remain.

Comment: Upvoted (terse!), but this has one serious flaw: READ seems to clear the answer beforehand. `KEYPATH="$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
#echo "Path to public key file (leave empty for $KEYPATH)?"
read -rt 20 -p "Path to public key file [$KEYPATH]? " KEYPATH
[[ -f $KEYPATH ]] || echo "Not a file: $KEYPATH. Exiting."` If $KEYPATH is put in line with `read` call, Bash complains that identifier ain't valid. I had to use default notation and another var: `DEFAULT_KEYPATH="$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
read -rt 20 -p "Path to public key file [Enter for $DEFAULT_KEYPATH]? " INPUT
KEYPATH=${INPUT:-$DEFAULT_KEYPATH}`

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in how you wrote your conditions using the `[[` builtin.

You need to change your conditions to:

```
function is_confirmed {

    read -rs -k 1 ans

    if [[ "${ans}" == "n" ]] || [[ "${ans}" == "N" ]]; then
        printf "No\n"
        return 1
    else if [[ "${ans}" == "y" ]] || [[ "${ans}" == "Y" ]]; then
        printf "Yes\n"
        return 0
    else if [[ -z "${ans}" ]]; then
        printf "Empty\n"
    else
        printf "Damn\n"
    fi

    return 1
}
```

To explain, the `[[` builtin tests just one condition, but you can chain multiple instances of `[[` with `&&` and `||`. Your code, in contrast, tried to test 2 conditions inside `[[` and used `||` as it's C/C++ usage.

More details available in `help [[` or `man bash`

Comment: thats not the problem :)

when I add `[[ "$ans" == "" ]]` to the Yes answer, when the user input is nothing, it falls back to "Damn", where I would suspect it would fall back to Yes

Comment: @MartinBroder I've added the conditions in case `$ans` is empty and none of the above. Add your assignment as necessary.